# an inequality about complex number

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

How to prove that

$|a-b|^\gamma\ge||a|^\gamma-|b|^\gamma|$

where $0\le\gamma<1$ and $a,b$ are complex numbers.

Is it a famous inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- We only need to show that if $x,y\geqslant 0$, we have $(x+y)^\gamma\leqslant x^\gamma+y^\gamma$ (then we use the result with $x=|a-b|$ and $y:=|b|$).
- We can assume that $y=1$ because we can divide in both sides by $y^\gamma$. We thus have to prove that for $x\geqslant 0$, $(x+1)^\gamma\leqslant x^\gamma+1$. One can define $f(x):=x^\gamma+1-(x+1)^\gamma$, then show that this function is non-decreasing and $f(0)=0$.

It's a generalization of triangular inequality.